# Как передать значения переменной с imacros в js скрипт

Tags: javascript, imacros

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в IMacros передать значение переменной в JS.

Как запустить JS в `imacros` понятно: URL `GOTO=imacros://run/?m=zamena.js`,
но как передать значение переменной в данный скрипт не понимаю.

Пытался сохранить значения переменной в txt, однако JS не может работать файлами на компьютере.

В самой переменной находится HTML. Скрипт должен заменить `br` на `< br />`. Подскажите, как это можно сделать. Как с помощью JS я знаю как это сделать: Regexp. Но как передать значение переменной не могу понять.

Comment: Вопрос более не актуален, сам нашел ответ: весь код imacros переместив на js и с помощью команды iimSet передавал данные с js в imacros. тогда как начальные данные те что html сделал чтобы сам js извлекал их. ех пол дня промучился но оно того стояло. =)